# AngularJS Scope.Push to Dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble adding a new row using AngularJS with a dropdown box in it.  I want it to add a new row and populate the dropdown in the row with values that were entered.  The issue is from the line of code below.  Everything is working on it except the dropdown isn't populating with the values entered.  It's just populating the whole JSON NewItems string.  Am I missing something really simple here?  Or is there a better way to do it?

```
  **`$scope.phones.push({ 'name': $scope.name, 'snippet': $scope.snippet, 'dropdown': [{ Item: $scope.NewItems }] });`**
```

```js
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [
      {
          'name': 'Nexus S',
          'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
          'dropdown': [{ 'Item': 'Nexus 1' }, { 'Item': 'Nexus 2' }, { 'Item': 'Nexus 3' }],
      },
      {
          'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
          'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
          'dropdown': [{ 'Item': 'XOOM 1' }, { 'Item': 'XOOM 2' }, { 'Item': 'XOOM 3' }],
      },
      {
          'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
          'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
          'dropdown': [{ 'Item': 'MOTOROLA 1' }, { 'Item': 'MOTOROLA 2' }, { 'Item': 'MOTOROLA 3' }],
      }
    ];

    $scope.NewItems = [{ Itemz: '-Select-' }];


    $scope.addRow = function () {
        
        $scope.phones.push({ 'name': $scope.name, 'snippet': $scope.snippet, 'dropdown': [{ Item: $scope.NewItems }] });
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.snippet = '';
        $scope.dropdown.Item = '';
        $scope.NewItems = [{ Itemz: '-Select-' }];
    };

    $scope.AddItem = function () { $scope.NewItems.push({ Itemz: $scope.dropdown.Item }) };
 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>Table</h2>



<html ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

    <table border="1" >
        <tr style="background-color:#eeeeee;">
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Snippet
            </th>
            <th>
                Selection

            </th>

        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="phone in phones">
            <td>{{phone.name}}</td>
            <td>{{phone.snippet}}</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option ng-repeat="itemSelect in phone.dropdown">{{itemSelect.Item}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRow()" style="border:outset 1px #cccccc; margin-top:50px; padding:10px; width:300px; ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                       ng-model="name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Snippet</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snippet"
                       ng-model="snippet" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Dropdown</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dropdown"
                       ng-model="dropdown.Item" />
                <input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="AddItem()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat="NewItemAdded in NewItems">
                        <td>
                            {{NewItemAdded.Itemz}}
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="padding-left:110px">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```